# using raw sockets

Tags: sockets, network-programming

is it possible to use raw sockets (on windows) to close a connection between 2 hosts?
if yes then is this the best practice. i am not a cracker, i have a security assignment of 2 phases. phase 1- is to create a sniffer. phase 2- is to create a raw socket and choose a sniffed packet and attack the connection to close it. so how should i do phase 2?
should i create the socket and flood the port?would this shutdown the connection or the operating systems are more secured and won't allow this?
should i trace the syn and acks and send FINs or RST ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but believe you can. I think that's how the Great Firewall of China works, sending RST packets on the connections it doesn't like. Probably you will need to spoof source address.